# PowerQuery - add column with end of month where the last day is not included in the data

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with dates and would like to add a column to display the end of the month.

Normally this is simple, but my problem is, in some cases the last day of the month is not included in the data. I would like to add the last day available in the report as the last day of the month:

Date format: mm/dd/yy

| Date | End Of month | What I need |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/10/2023 | 31/10/2023 | 20/10/2023 |
| 06/10/2023 | 31/10/2023 | 20/10/2023 |
| 10/10/2023 | 31/10/2023 | 20/10/2023 |
| 20/10/2023 | 31/10/2023 | 20/10/2023 |
| 05/09/2023 | 30/09/2023 | 29/09/2023 |
| 16/09/2023 | 30/09/2023 | 29/09/2023 |
| 29/09/2023 | 30/09/2023 | 29/09/2023 |

Is there a simple way to achieve that?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powerquery (date format irrelevant)

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "LastDate",  (x)=>List.Max(Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each Date.EndOfMonth(x[Date])=Date.EndOfMonth([Date]))[Date]),type date)
in #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

alternate

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "End of Month", each Date.EndOfMonth([Date])),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"End of Month"}, {{"Max Date", each List.Max([Date]), type nullable date}, {"data", each _, type table [Date=nullable date, End of Month=date]}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Date"}, {"Date"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

Comment: Hello @horseyride, thank you for your reply. With the first option I get a new column where all the values are "Function", When I click on it it wants me to enter a value for parameter x. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The code works as expected.  In your version, check the formula bar and remove the word: each

Answer (score 1):

And in DAX if you wanted a Calculate Column:

```
EndOfMonth = 
  var cDate = [Date]
  RETURN CALCULATE(LASTDATE('YourTable'[Date]), ALL('YourTable'), 'YourTable'[Date] <= EOMONTH(cDate, 0))
```